# How to draw multiple geometries at one layer like featureCollection?

Tags: angular, openlayers, geojson

I have the following json file for drawing? I am trying to draw point and linestring like feature collection. I have:

```
    geodata:
        [
            {"layer_id":3,"layer_name":"Uncleaned streets Scenario 1","layer_data":{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[29.759521,59.996136]}},
                        {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[30.2983368,59.9077531],[30.2982537,59.9077256],[30.2981382,59.9076843],[30.2976979,59.9075158],[30.2976087,59.9074943],[30.2975072,59.9074829],[30.2973542,59.9074796],[30.2964844,59.9075143],[30.2956987,59.9075457],[30.2950936,59.9075718],[30.294995,59.9075938],[30.2949041,59.9076188]]}}]}
                },
        ];
```

In my ts file I created feature based on geometry type:

```
    if(feature.geometry.type.toLowerCase() === 'point') {
      result =  new Feature(
        new Point(
          transform(...
          )
        )
      );
    } else if(feature.geometry.type.toLowerCase() === 'linestring') {
      result =  new Feature(
        new LineString(
          (feature.geometry.coordinates as Array<Coordinate>).map(coord => {
            return transform(
              ...
            )
          }),
        )
      );
    }
```

And afterwards I add layers to the map:

```
 private _initLayers() {
    const layers: Array<VectorLayer<any>> = [];
    this._layersDataState.items.forEach((layerData, index) => {
      const mapFeatures: Array<Feature> = [];
      layerData.layer_data.features.forEach(feature => {
        const mapFeature = this._createMapFeature(feature, layerData.layer_name);
        if(mapFeature) {
          mapFeatures.push(mapFeature);
        }
      });
     //add feature and put it to the layer
      const layer = this._createLayer(layerData, index, mapFeatures);
      if(layer) {
        layers.push(layer);
      }
    });
  };
```